# App crashes when trying to show Apple payment page on iPhone 6s plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to make payment using Apple pay when I press pay button on Simulator it works fine. But When I try to pay using device iPhone 6s plus it not shows any payment page and crashes.

The crash log is given below

```
Incident Identifier: 73833AED-4533-4507-8374-356D49E67DA8
CrashReporter Key:   eeee419dcac8e895c3d419e32bb90f44767f9c96
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,2
Process:             EndCap [1184]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/375353D7-8055-4E9E-AA5A-6AF64D553BB5/EndCap.app/EndCap
Identifier:          com.kelly.endcap
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Date/Time:           2016-07-22 15:51:12.12 +0500
Launch Time:         2016-07-22 15:50:43.43 +0500
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.2 (13F69)
Report Version:      105
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0
Filtered syslog:
None found
Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1833a6db0 0x182a0bf80 0x188886fb4 0x188889890 0x1885ff3cc 0x19510484c 0x100079b58 0x18853cbe8 0x18853cb64 0x188524870 0x18853c454 0x18853c084 0x188534c20 0x18850504c 0x1950d945c 0x188503628 0x18335d09c 0x18335cb30 0x18335a830 0x183284c50 0x184b6c088 0x18856e088 0x1000aa260 0x182e228b8)
Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
1.740737     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183a2bf18 TCP Conn 0x13df3f3c0 complete. fd: 10, err: 0
1.742165     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183a2d444 TCP Conn 0x13df3f3c0 event 1. err: 0
1.747401     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183a2bf18 TCP Conn 0x13deb9230 complete. fd: 8, err: 0
1.748859     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183a2d444 TCP Conn 0x13deb9230 event 1. err: 0
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f4011c 0x182f24000 + 114972
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018300cef8 0x183008000 + 20216
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182eb1dac 0x182e50000 + 400812
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001829e53f4 0x1829e4000 + 5108
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182a01e98 0x1829e4000 + 122520
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182a0c248 0x182a04000 + 33352
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001829fef44 0x1829e4000 + 110404
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001829feb10 0x1829e4000 + 109328
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182a0c120 0x182a04000 + 33056
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183284cf8 0x18327c000 + 36088
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184b6c088 0x184b60000 + 49288
11  UIKit                           0x000000018856e088 0x1884f0000 + 516232
12  EndCap                          0x00000001000aa260 0x100054000 + 352864
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182e228b8 0x182e20000 + 10424
Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f414d8 0x182f24000 + 120024
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182e047d8 0x182df0000 + 83928
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182df3648 0x182df0000 + 13896
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f40b48 0x182f24000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009530 0x183008000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009020 0x183008000 + 4128
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f40b48 0x182f24000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009530 0x183008000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009020 0x183008000 + 4128
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f40b48 0x182f24000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009530 0x183008000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009020 0x183008000 + 4128
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f40b48 0x182f24000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009530 0x183008000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009020 0x183008000 + 4128
Thread 6 name:  WebThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f24fd8 0x182f24000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f24e54 0x182f24000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018335cc60 0x18327c000 + 920672
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018335a964 0x18327c000 + 911716
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183284c50 0x18327c000 + 35920
5   WebCore                         0x000000018727261c 0x1871fc000 + 484892
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018300bb28 0x183008000 + 15144
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018300ba8c 0x183008000 + 14988
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009028 0x183008000 + 4136
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f40b48 0x182f24000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009530 0x183008000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009020 0x183008000 + 4128
Thread 8 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f24fd8 0x182f24000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f24e54 0x182f24000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018335cc60 0x18327c000 + 920672
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018335a964 0x18327c000 + 911716
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183284c50 0x18327c000 + 35920
5   Foundation                      0x0000000183c94cfc 0x183c88000 + 52476
6   Foundation                      0x0000000183cea030 0x183c88000 + 401456
7   EndCap                          0x00000001000663c8 0x100054000 + 74696
8   Foundation                      0x0000000183d7be4c 0x183c88000 + 998988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018300bb28 0x183008000 + 15144
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018300ba8c 0x183008000 + 14988
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009028 0x183008000 + 4136
Thread 9 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f24fd8 0x182f24000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f24e54 0x182f24000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018335cc60 0x18327c000 + 920672
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018335a964 0x18327c000 + 911716
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183284c50 0x18327c000 + 35920
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183a05c68 0x183958000 + 711784
6   Foundation                      0x0000000183d7be4c 0x183c88000 + 998988
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018300bb28 0x183008000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018300ba8c 0x183008000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009028 0x183008000 + 4136
Thread 10 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182f40344 0x182f24000 + 115524
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833631c8 0x18327c000 + 946632
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018300bb28 0x183008000 + 15144
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018300ba8c 0x183008000 + 14988
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183009028 0x183008000 + 4136
Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000013f1dcf07
    x4: 0x0000000182a02e02   x5: 0x000000016fdab520   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x00000000ffffffff  x15: 0x00000000fffffff5
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001a1d94000  x21: 0x000000016fdab520  x22: 0x000000013de188a0  x23: 0x00000001a1da0150
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x2c00f9f3d0256680  x26: 0x000000013de17a70  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001  fp: 0x000000016fdab480   lr: 0x000000018300cef8
    sp: 0x000000016fdab460   pc: 0x0000000182f4011c cpsr: 0x00000000
Binary Images:
0x100054000 - 0x100103fff EndCap arm64  <ad20b26e95dc3db7b224649de8442f0a> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/375353D7-8055-4E9E-AA5A-6AF64D553BB5/EndCap.app/EndCap
0x102934000 - 0x102937fff GeoServices arm64  <c4c46b3fa23b3308895f8f580c921106> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GeoServices.axbundle/GeoServices
0x102940000 - 0x102947fff ContactsUI arm64  <07006880c67c31aba08a5cf1dea62dce> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/ContactsUI.axbundle/ContactsUI
0x102954000 - 0x102957fff SpringBoardUIServices arm64  <0972934c2b9036ea84f17025b3145fef> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/SpringBoardUIServices.axbundle/SpringBoardUIServices
0x102960000 - 0x102963fff CoreRecognition arm64  <6edd27518cf73df3974ee9c498fc34aa> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CoreRecognition.axbundle/CoreRecognition
0x10296c000 - 0x10296ffff WatchKit arm64  <ec1bdec24f003a59badb807610c246ee> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/WatchKit.axbundle/WatchKit
0x102978000 - 0x10297bfff SpringBoardFoundation arm64  <61682523019639d4a90cd541e47c19b1> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/SpringBoardFoundation.axbundle/SpringBoardFoundation
0x102984000 - 0x1029a3fff VectorKit arm64  <dbb52f717ffd3f78954e8ffd8a4301a6> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/VectorKit.axbundle/VectorKit
0x1029cc000 - 0x1029d3fff PreferencesFramework arm64  <513a24b0cc8d3a408020bb906b3c3826> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/PreferencesFramework.axbundle/PreferencesFramework
0x1029e4000 - 0x1029ebfff TelephonyUIFramework arm64  <1c3da556fe8d33258096ec218724036f> 
----------*
```

Comment: Try searching for information on how to symbolicate a crash log.  It makes them a lot more useful.

Comment: yeah i have tried apple documentation says that it is taking extra time due to which OS closes the ap but on my case it is not taking too much time. as soon as i tap on Pay button its immidiately get crashed . but simulator works fine.

Comment: Your payment request is probably invalid. Are you checking that the view controller you're creating is not nil?

Comment: no i am just trying to display payment controller actionsheet like view (apple pay) if it is nil why it appears in simulators ?

Comment: if you are connected to debugger then just have a breakpoint on exception.

Comment: "if it is nil why it appears in simulators" - because the Simulator is not real hardware. It's not an exact recreation of how the hardware behaves.

Comment: okay i will check it what i have to do if it is nil ? as i hace implemmented delegate methods already ...

Comment: Okay i have found the Isssue i am no in supported region of apple pay I am from Pakistan.  and according to my openion it should not give me the crash it should give me the alert of unsupported region .

Comment: You should be calling `canMakePaymentsWithNetworks` before invoking the view controller, and not displaying it if that call returns NO.

Comment: yes i am calling it  if it return no .... i show him a custom paymentview else it show him apple pay.